# Element gets removed when scrolling down (Jquery)

Tags: jquery

This is my jquery.

```
var count = 0;
    $(window).scroll(function(event){       

        var scrolled = $(this).scrollTop();     

        if (scrolled > count){  
            //scroll down
            count++;
            $('#nav-wrap').addClass('active');      
        }


        else {          
            //scroll up
            count--; 
            $('#nav-wrap').removeClass('active');
        }           
    });
```

When I scroll down my fb-like button it's getting removed. I don't know what affects it since I barely understand much about Jquery.

Thanks,

Comment: Does that jQuery have anything at all to do with your FB like button? Is it inside #nav-wrap? What is the HTML around the like button? What is the CSS in the active class?  Honestly that code doesn't look like it's the issue, unless the FB button is inside of nav-wrap and is only visible if that div has a class of active.

Comment: This is toggling on/off a class `active` on some element with an `id=nav-wrap` on it. If the fb-like button is nested inside that element, its possible there's some rule(s) in the CSS that's telling it to only display if a parent element has an "active" class, e.g. `.fb-button { display: none }`, `.active .fb-button { display: block }`. Without knowing more of the HTML/CSS there's not much more we can say. Try learning/using the browser devtools to find more info about that button.
If the button _isn't_ nested in the element with `id=nav-wrap`, this code probably isn't the culprit.

Comment: I got the logic... Thanks for bringing that up... I'll let you guys know if I get it fixed...

Comment: Already fixed it... Thanks guys...